# What causes Templars to try to knock down the ziplines?

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-revelations

Is it random? Does your presence/alertness bar have any impact on whether Templars will try to dismantle the zipline?

Comment: They do try that?

Comment: I never saw them trying to knock down ziplines during my playthrough either.  Do you have a screenshot or a reference for what you're seeing them do?

Comment: folow this link i did the recording myself sorry if its not that clear http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSn6d7Vi2aI&feature=g-upl&context=G231fcfcAUAAAAAAAAAA i hope the link works.

Comment: IIRC, that's the _only_ instance of them showing like that.  I remember seeing that too in the eastern side of Constantinople.  It never actually goes down, they were just there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen these guys all over, generally in zones still controlled by the Templars. It never occurred to me that they were trying to *dismantle* the ziplines - they just seemed to be working on them in some way. It made sense in my head since these Templars always seemed to be working on the tops of ziplines while regular guards always seemed to be stationed at the bottoms of ziplines (so that I could assassinate them more conveniently).

To answer your question, I imagine that when Templars control a zone, they know Assassins might try to gain access via zipline, so they try to destroy it. But as far as I know they never get far enough to actually disable a zipline. I think it's just a visual cue to let you know that you're in a Templar-ridden area and that they want to disable your ability to move around.

Comment: Actually, for me, they only appear in a zone I cleared recently.After I kill them, I never see them again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens whenever a Den is re-taken by the Templars.